# Encoding Extreme #2

Tags: riddle, mathematics

Yesterday a mysterious man came to my house. I didn't open the door, because I didn't know him.

Later I found a message under the door as show below:

```
1+1-1·0*1 n 1*9/9 y·w 2^2 n sqrt(49) sqrt(9) d·140/2·126/2·y 0*0 ur·fr 26/2 nd!
```

What does the message say?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer:**

> "I only wanted to be your friend!"

**Reason:**

> **Each equation represents [Leet](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) letters.**
>  1+1-1 = 1 or I
>  0*1 = 0 or O
>  1*9/9 = 1 or L
>  2^2 = 4 or A
>  sqrt(49) = 7 or T
>  sqrt(9) = 3 or E
>  140/2 = 70 or TO
>  126/2 = 63 or BE (bE)
>  0*0 = 0 or O
>  26/2 = 13 or IE
>  **Which combined with the letters included between equations creates the below text in Leet:**
>  *"1 0n1y w4n73d 70 63 y0ur fr13nd!"*

Comment: Great done! 63 is bE, not BE, whatever.

Comment: @Alex82 oic XD 4w350m3!